# Magento 2 : How to Insert Category Name as Meta-Description of Each Category From Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, category-products, meta-tags, custom-variable

From admin, **I'm trying to insert category name as a variable** in metatags (something like {category name} in meta description).

I **go to admin:** `Products -> Categories`. From the details of Category, In Search Engine Optimization dropdown., I am adding Meta Description which includes category name like in curly brackets {category name}. But, Im not able to do..

Not sure Im doing it right, Is there any way or certain variable for Category name, which we can insert like this.

Comment: You can do this using magento event observer.

Comment: how can we do it_ Can you give me an example to add same metatags with individual category names in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this things with custom extension.

1. app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
         <observer name="catalog_metadescription" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Categorysaveafter" />
      </event>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create another file at this location.

   ```
   app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\Categorysaveafter.php

   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

   use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

   class Categorysaveafter implements ObserverInterface
   {
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
      {
          //THIS CALLED WHEN YOU SAVE ANY CATEGORY
          // DO YOUR CODE TO GET CATEGORY NAME AND SET IN META
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Dhiren, Just one more thing, I had a Category for which I added its meta title from backoffice. And I want to use this metatitle in meta description, Is there any way to extract this meta title.. I tried with same code you provided initiating an instance, but it returns Magento default title - (which is not the one, I stored via backoffice)

Comment: You need to debug that, why you don't get those store meta title.

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it, So it will help comminity as well.